# Openwrt - Prevent devices from acquiring a global unicast IPv6 address

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, openwrt

There are some IoT devices on my network which acquire a `2601:` IPv6 address. Since that address falls in the range of my ISP, I assume these IoT devices are getting that assignment from some IPv6 DHCP server operated by my ISP. It is messing up various device to device communication logic in my LAN. I still want locally assigned IPv6 addresses however. How can I prevent my devices from getting assigned a Global Unicast address?

Comment: You've got to tell us how you have OpenWrt set up with respect to IPv6. Generally, if your home LAN devices are behind an IPv4 NAPT gateway (that is, a typical home gateway router) and are still getting routable v6 addresses, it's because your router is retrieving a v6 prefix from your ISP via DHCP6-PD, and advertising that prefix via v6 router advertisements.

Comment: @Spiff, You gave me the hint I needed. My devices still get `fe80` addresses while no longer acquiring a Global Unicast address after I set `dhcp.lan.ra_management=0` and deleted `dhcp.lan.ra` and `dhcp.lan.ra_slaac`. That might not be the standard way of doing it. I'm open to recommendations.

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out. When you find a solution for yourself like this, it's proper to post your own Answer on your own Question, and then click the checkmark next to your own Answer to accept it as the official answer and mark the question as resolved. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uci set dhcp.lan.ra_management=0
uci delete dhcp.lan.ra
uci delete dhcp.lan.ra_slaac
```

After running the commands above and rebooting the router, devices on `lan` network no longer receive Global Unicast (2000::/3) addresses. This doesn't prevent them from getting Link-Local (fe80::/10) addresses.

Note that some devices in the network may need a reboot in order for the Global Unicast address to stop showing up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).